# StateModel.AddModelError() but on a redirect?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, f#

So I have this logic in my LoginController to show an error to the user after a bad login attempt:

```ml
[<HandleError>]
type LoginController() =
    inherit Controller()

    [<HttpPost>]
    member this.Index
        (user: string, password: string) =
            if (WebDbAccess.IsValidUser user password) then
                this.Session.["user"] <- user
                RedirectResult("lobby") :> ActionResult
            else
                this.ModelState.AddModelError ("login", "The user or password is incorrect.")
                this.Index()
```

To show this error, I just add this in the view:

```ml
@Html.ValidationMessage("login")
```

Now, when the session expires, I would like to show the Login page but with an error message about the session expiration, however the ModelState gets ignored once I use the RedirectResult() method:

```ml
[<HandleError>]
type LobbyController() =
    inherit Controller()

    member this.Index() =
        if not (FsWeb.Global.IsUserLoggedIn(this.Session)) then
            this.ModelState.AddModelError ("session", "Invalid or expired session")
            RedirectResult("/") :> ActionResult
        else
            this.View("Chart", model) :> ActionResult
```

How could I send an error to a modelState of a redirect?

Answer (score 1):

Use `TempData` like this:

```
if not (FsWeb.Global.IsUserLoggedIn(this.Session)) then
    this.ModelState.AddModelError ("session", "Invalid or expired session")
    TempData.["Error"] <- "Invalid or expired session"
    RedirectResult("/") :> ActionResult
```

In view of redirected action:

```
@{
    if(TempData["Error"] != null)
    {
        string Message = TempData["Error"] as string;
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer (I corrected your F# code to be syntactically correct). The problem about this approach is that the message doesn't get the same style as the error message of a StateModel represented with `@Html.ValidationMessage("login")`, any idea how to fix that?

Comment: you can copy the html using firebug and apply that html, it wil be in same style that way

Comment: that doesn't sound very clean

Comment: yes but in that view you will not have the same model, you can make custom html helper which you can use to display error messages,,

Answer (score 1):

Don't use TempData, that is basically session and will fail in a web farm that is configured with affinities.  Redirect with a value in the RouteValueDictionary and check for it on the recieving end.

if you return RedirectToAction() one of the parameters is the route value dictionary.  You can do a

```
return RedirectToAction("SomeView", "SomeController", new {
  SomeProperty = SomeValue,
  //more stuff if you want
});
```

If the action you redirected to has either a matching property on the model or a matching parameter in the controller method parameter list it will get populated as long as the name matches.  This way you can pass the value and keep things stateless.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, as you can see, I'm already using the Session property of the controllers... (and as far as I have read, using a State provider in ASP.NET different to InProc would fix this). Can you provide more info (a link?) about a RouteValueDictionary snippet? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `TempData` since it was designed for passing single-use data between controllers

Comment: any code sample of how to pass it and how to grab it from the view? thanks